# Element with fixed position hides by half on scroll from mobile

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, fixed

I want to fix an element's position (.topsection) while scrolling down. Desktop works fine, but from mobile it hides by half.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDigL.jpg)

[My website](https://icookyoueat.ru/myweb/domain/)

*Note*: An element with class .topsection-container needs as wrapper for changing background-color on scroll event in js.

`HTML`

```
<div class="topblock">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="topsection-container">
      <div class="topsection">
        `//some code...`
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.topsection-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}

.topsection {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 10% 0 10%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Mobile screen seems works well on you mentioned website. Add some screenshot that clarifies what you want exactly

Comment: @cursorrux I've edited the post and attached a screenshot. So the fixed element is hidden by half when scrolling down. When scroll to the top it shows correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: fixed` works well in your code, the only issue is `body` scroll down in mobile screen that's why, half of `.topsection-container` scrolled up. `body` having extra scroll things which let's them scroll.

Add following CSS and try:

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: change : to ; after "auto" to save someones time ;)
Thanks for an answer!